# ngx-select-dropdown, how to modify searchPlaceholder placement on screen

Tags: html, angular

i can't figure out how to move the searchPlaceholder keyword after i click on the
search bar. It goes up badly like in the image below.

[wrong search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj2O3.png)

I want the search word "Cautare" to either go away completely or align perfectly in between the borders.

Here is my html code:

```
<ngx-select-dropdown class="drop-down d-block" [config]="specialistConfig" 
                             [(ngModel)]="selectedSpecialist"
                             [options]="specialists" (change)="loadEvents()">
</ngx-select-dropdown>
```

And this is the scss part:

```
this.specialistConfig = {
      displayKey: 'fullName',
      search: true,
      searchPlaceholder: 'Căutare...',
      placeholder: 'Selectează un specialist...',
      noResultsFound: 'Nu au fost găsite rezultate!',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ngx-dropdown-container .ngx-dropdown-list-container .search-container input:focus + label {
    transform: translateY(-2px) scale(0.8);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Try to modify this style as per your requirement and add it to your style sheet.

use `!important` if needed